# Sein and Haben in Perfect

Tags: sentence-structure, german-to-english, perfect-tense, sein-or-haben

I read the sentence below but I do not understand the "change of state" part; please help me.

> A verb takes sein in perfect if and only if the verb is used
> intransitively AND the nominative subject undergoes a **change of
> state**, except for bleiben, which is the lone exception.

The examples given are

> Er hat auf den Mann geschossen

and

> Die Kugel ist aus dem Gewehr geschossen

Comment: "If and only if" sounds a bit precise for a grammatical rule; this isn't mathematics. In my experience there are always exceptions and cases where a rule is difficult to interpret. Movement from one place to another usually means you use *sein*, so I guess the movement is supposed to be a "change of state" in the rule, but it's not obvious. In *Die Hunde sind dem Fuchs gefolgt,* the verb has a dative object, so not intransitive. In *Was ist passiert?*, are we saying *was* had 'a change of state'? In *Du bist gut klargekommen,* the point is that there is no 'change of state'.

Comment: I think everybody learning German learns that verbs of movement use *sein* for the perfect. Ironically, *sich bewegen* uses *haben*. However, this is easily explained by the fact that *sich bewegen* is the reflexive form of *bewegen* which is transitive.

Answer (score 3):

> Er hat auf den Mann geschossen.

*Er* is subject and does not undergo a change of state, which explains why *haben* is used with the perfect.

> Die Kugel ist aus dem Gewehr geschossen.

The bullet is subject and undergoes a change of state by moving out of the gun, which explains why *sein* is used with the perfect.

Actually, *schießen* is not one but two verbs. One means *to shoot* and its perfect uses *haben*. The other means something like *to move very fast* and its perfect uses *sein*.